# Native counter on a for-loop iterative in python

Tags: python

When I'm iterating over an iterable in python, I used to keep track of where I am in the iteration more or less like so, by creating an iterator outside the loop and incrementing it within:

```
i = 0
for x in res:
    if not(i % 10):
        print("On count {}".format(unicode(i)))
    f(x)
    i +=1
```

So, on my 6 lines of loop, 4 of them are dedicated to the counter i.

I know I can also use enumerate as:

```
for i,x in enumerate(res):
    if not(i % 10):
        print("On count {}".format(unicode(i)))
    f(x)
```

Which saves 2 lines.

I was wondering if there was /still/ a more concise way of dealing with this and providing pretty feedback to the user at some loop interval.  I suspect there may be something built in to the `__iter__` such that my x may be able to call some kind of count?  `x.___count___` or something such that I don't need to even call enumerate?

Also, does anyone have advice on providing this kind of feedback in a more functional style?  How would I embed this counter in a map, rather than for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of to combine them, would be to write a generator, and have that do the printing. The overall code lines is the same, but you could write it once and use it multiple times:

```
def status_generator(iterable, update_interval=10):
    for i, x in enumerate(iterable):
        if not (i % update_interval):
            print("On count {}".format(unicode(i)))
        yield x

map(f, status_generator(my_iterable))
```

Answer (score 4):

`enumerate` is definitely the correct way of doing this.

1. Every python programmer knows `enumerate`. It's built-in and its intent is immediately obvious. Always go for built-in if possible.
2. `enumerate` keeps your concerns separate. Walking a collection and counting iterations are different useful functions, reusable under different contexts.
3. `enumerate` forces explicit declaration of the counter variable. If you're going to use it, this beats the hell out of `__count__`, a mysterious attribute spawned behind curtains. The sole fact of having `enumerate` tells the reader that the iteration index is important.

Go for `enumerate`.

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate` is the best and most widely used way to do what you've done. If you want to map functions onto iterables, you can always use a list comprehension or the map function, although a list comprehension is often more efficient in my experience. So if you want to change all the 10s into a string in a list:

```
>>> l = list(range(1, 100))
>>> ['a ten!' if i % 10 == 0 else v for i, v in enumerate(l)]
['a ten!', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a ten!', 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 'a ten!', 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 'a ten!', 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 'a ten!', 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 'a ten!', 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 'a ten!', 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 'a ten!', 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 'a ten!', 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 'a ten!', 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

You can do the same with `map`:

```
>>> map(lambda x: 'a ten!' if x[0] % 10 == 0 else x[1], enumerate(l))
['a ten!', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a ten!', 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 'a ten!', 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 'a ten!', 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 'a ten!', 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 'a ten!', 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 'a ten!', 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 'a ten!', 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 'a ten!', 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 'a ten!', 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```